# Install tesseract offline in RHEL

Tags: rhel, yum, tesseract

I have an RHEL based server that does not connect to the internet. I need to install Tesseract >4.0 on this server. Therefore, my option was to download RPM packages from another and move them to the server and install using `rpm` command. I have used (https://build.opensuse.org/project/show/home:Alexander_Pozdnyakov) from the official tesseract documentation to download the RPM.

The issue is when I try to install those RPMs, they have a lot of other dependencies which is very difficult to get one by one. Are there any other alternatives to install tesseract without connecting to the internet? Or any other source to download all RPMs at once?

Answer (score 2):

Solution N1:

On a similar PC which is connected to the Internet do the following (under root/sudo):

```
dnf install --downloadonly Tesseract.rpm
```

Then copy all the downloaded RPMs from `/var/cache/dnf` to your destination PC and run

```
rpm -ivh *rpm
```

---

Solution N2:

Granted you have a RedHat DVD install disk either mounted or extracted to `/media/dvd` create a repo file for yum (save it as `/etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-dvd.repo`):

```
[RHEL-DVD-Repository]
name=DVD-RHEL Repository
baseurl=file:///media/dvd
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

and then run (under root/sudo):

```
dnf install Tesseract.rpm
```

Comment: It's possible you will need to substitute `dnf` with `yum`, depending on the RHEL version.